# É possível utilizar min, max e step em CSS?

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma input do tipo `number` com um `min` e o `max` em HTML. é possível utilizar esse `min`, `max` e o `step` no CSS?

```
<input class=input_number id=delai type=number min=1 max=10 step=2 name=delai required />
```

Em CSS, algo deste género:

```
#delai{ min:1;max:10;step:2}
```

Comment: Isso que você está querendo fazer não é função do CSS. O CSS é usado para a formatação visual de um documento e não para adicionar funcionalidades explicitamente. Outras ferramentas se encarregam de realizar esse tipo de modificação (por exemplo javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Como já referido, CSS não serve para definir valores mas sim para definir formatação, o aspeto visual do elemento.

Podes no entanto recorrer a JavaScript para esse efeito.

### Exemplo com jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#delay").attr({
    "min": 2,
    "max": 10,
    "step": 2
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="delay" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5" />
```

### Exemplo com JavaScript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var meuCampo = document.getElementById("delay");

  meuCampo.min = 2;
  meuCampo.max = 10;
  meuCampo.step = 2;

}, false);
```

```html
<input id="delay" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="5" />
```

---

<sup>**Nota:** Se a ideia é definir determinada formatação CSS com base no valor do atributo, podes ver a solução na resposta do [@Iago Correia Guimarães](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/73901/223).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

você não consegue mudar o valor do atributo de um elemento com css mas consegue definir o estilo de determinado elemento pelo seu valor usando o atributo data do html.
Exemplo:

```
<input id="delai" type="number" data-min="1" />
```

e no css:

```
#delai[data-min='1']{ seu estilo aqui }
```

Comment: claro que não vai conseguir mudar o valor do input, somente o estilo

Comment: verdade, até editei meu post